# How to disable next button in QWizard

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

**What I'm trying to do**

I am trying to create a subclass of QWizardPage that looks somewhat like this,but has a slight tweak. I want to disable the next button when a counter variable is more than 0. (It can't be 0 from the get-go due to some functionality that requires it to go x..x-1...0).

**What I've tried**

*Reimplement isComplete() and emit completeChanged() in the constructor*

```
bool DemoWizardPage::isComplete()
{
  return ! (counter > 0); //Also tried just return false;
}
```

*Reimplement `initializePage` and disable the next button from there*

```
void DemoWizardPage::initializePage()
{
  qDebug() << "QWizardPage:: initialize page";

  if (!this->isComplete())
  {
    qDebug() << "try to turn off next button";
    wizard()->button(QWizard::NextButton)->setDisabled(true);

    qDebug() << "next button enabled? "
             << wizard()->button(QWizard::NextButton)->isEnabled();
  }
}
```

**Results so far**

From stepping through the code I can see that the next button is disabled when the page loads. But then it is enabled again due to these 2 lines in QWizardPrivate (taken from qwizard.cpp)

```
 bool complete = page && page->isComplete();
 btn.next->setEnabled(canContinue && complete);
```

I am quite baffled as to why isComplete() is returning true here. I mean, I set my counter to be 2 at the beginning and I never decrease it. (And yes, I do emit a `completeChanged()` whenever I set the counter).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QWizard automatically manages the state of Next button based on the QWizardPage::isComplete(), you should not implement that functionality yourself in initializePage(). The reason your isComplete() is not being called is that it doesn't actually overwrite QWizardPage::isComplete **const** from QWizardPage. Declare your function **const** and it will properly overwrite the original function.